# How do I read a boost<double>matrix from .txt file in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, input, boost

I have a .txt file which has the following lines

```
1 4 6
2 9 8

2 5 6
2 8 9
4 5 7
```

How to read these two blocks into two boost matrices A and B.

[Edited]
Sorry for insufficient information.
I know how to create boost matrix. I know how to read from a file using loop. For a simple 3x3 matrix I tried this.

```
 matrix<double> C(3, 3);
    std::ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open("foo.txt");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            in_file >> C[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    in_file.close();
    std::cout << C;
```

the foo.txt contains

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But it is not able to read.
Can you also please explain how to read two different matrices from the same file, like in the first case.

Thank you.

Comment: Whay is your problem? Reading the lines or assigning the result to the matrix? Please show your code so that we can help you

Comment: do you know how to read numbers from a file? Do you know how to construct a boost matrix and assign its elements? I think thats all you need. Please show what you tried and explain where you got stuck

Comment: does sizes of this matrices are fixed or should be detected from file format?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Does " it is not able to read" mean that it does not compile? That you get an error at runtime? Or that nothing is printed on the screen? From here it's hard to guess...

Comment: Vote to close as typo ([wrong operator used to access matrix elements](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6ZFY41bRn0g4ZT5s)). Please read [ask] since you didn't explained that this is compilation error and you should.